# Binary output for Change Detection using Convolutional Neural Networks

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, deconvolution

Let's say I have 2 images taken at the same location but at different times. I need to build a model that detects if there is any change between these 2 images.

This is somehow similar to the foreground segmentation/background subtraction/scene change detection problems whose plenty of research works was deployed (For [reference](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330695424_ChangeNet_A_Deep_Learning_Architecture_for_Visual_Change_Detection_Subvolume_B)):
[image]

However, the scope of those problems is far beyond what I want to do. They extract features by CNN from original images and then concatenate extracted features to a greyscale output image by Deconvolutional techniques. For me, I just want to extract features and eventually output a binary (1 or 0) value: 1 if there is any change between 2 images, 0 if there is not. In other words, I don't want to implement the Deconvolutional part.

I have 2 problems:

1. The CD2014 dataset (and also other relevant datasets) have only
   ground truths in greyscale images format, not my desired output
   (binary 1/0 format).
2. Furthermore, since my problem is different from
   those papers, I cannot find a suitable model to use, I tend to use
   VGG-16 but there is no proof that it will work in my problem.

Can you suggest me any solutions or materials in this scope?

Answer (score 1):

There is this paper : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.09111.pdf
Its look like what you want to do !

In the paper they output a Heatmap of the changes between the two images, but you could just detect if there is activation or certain amount of activations to output your binary classification.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Sir, it seems to be the only solution for me currently. I am surprised that there is little researches or tutorials about this simple problem.